# Trying to find a book where main character is female and falls in love with a dragon who later dies and turns into a man

Tags: story-identification

The girl takes a ship to an island where dragons live. She picks leaves from trees and fruit that are worth a lot in money. She ends up being able to speak dragon speech and eventually falls in love with a dragon. The dragon gets killed by a demon who tries to kill her. The dragon reawakens as a human. What is this book??

Answer (score 6):

**Song in the Silence** by Elizabeth Kerner.

She finds a ship to the Dragon Isle for the Lansip harvest that used to occur every ten years, but no ship has returned from the trip in over 100 years due to the violent storms that lie between Kolmar and the Dragon Isle. After travelling on the ship with her father Marik lurking dangerously on board, she makes it safely to the Dragon Isle and meets Akhor, the mighty silver-scaled king of the Kantri ...

Akhor as an entity dies of his wounds, but he is mysteriously transformed into human form. Together they travel back to Kolmar and are eventually married.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_in_the_Silence

Comment: And it has two sequels, The Lesser Kindred & Redeeming the Lost